# How to count consecutive days in a table where days are duplicated "PostgresSQL"

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Hello I would like to know the highest count of consecutive days a user has trained for.

My **logs table** that stores the records looks like this:

| id | user_id | day | ground_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2023-01-24 10:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2023-01-25 10:00:00 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 2023-01-26 10:00:00 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 2023-01-27 10:00:00 |
| 5 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 2023-01-28 10:00:00 |

The closest I could get is with this query, which does work only if the user has trained on one ground at a day.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS days_in_row
FROM (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY day) - day AS grp
      FROM logs
      WHERE created_at >= '2023-01-24 00:00:00'
        AND user_id = 1) x
GROUP BY grp
```

**logs** table:

| id | user_id | day | ground_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2023-01-24 10:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2023-01-25 10:00:00 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 2023-01-26 10:00:00 |
| 4 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 2023-01-27 10:00:00 |
| 5 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 2023-01-28 10:00:00 |

*This query would return a count of 5 consecutive days which is correct.*

However my query doesn't work once a user trains multiple times on different training grounds in one day:

**logs** table:

| id | user_id | day | ground_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2023-01-24 10:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2023-01-25 10:00:00 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 2023-01-26 10:00:00 |
| 4 | 1 | 3 | **2** | 2023-01-26 10:00:00 |
| 5 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 2023-01-27 10:00:00 |

*Than the query from above would return a count of 2 consecutive days which is not what I expect instead I would expect the number four because the user has trained the following days in row (1,2,3,4).*

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Can you explicitly state what the input table and expected output table are?

Comment: Hello, not sure if this answers your question: the input and output table is the logs table

Comment: So you basically want to filter out all records not associated to the highest streak for each user, is it correct? Why do you have a duplicate `2023-01-26 10:00:00`?

Comment: I want to find out the highest count of consecutive days a user has trained for regardless of the ground_id

Comment: So the output is not the log table itself, but it has only two fields, the user id and the count?

Comment: Correct the output should at least contain the highest number of consecutive days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select only distinct data of interest first

```
SELECT min(created_at) start, COUNT(*) AS days_in_row
FROM (SELECT created_at, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY day) - day AS grp
      FROM (
        select distinct day, created_at
        from logs
        where created_at >= '2023-01-24 00:00:00'
        AND user_id = 1) t
     ) x
GROUP BY grp
```